# How to escape '@' from sign in username

Tags: mysql

I tried to connect to remote `mysql server` using `mysqlsh`, however the current username containers `@` so

```
mysqlsh mysql://userid@salesdeparment:@123.45.678.123:3306/ ....
```

reported an error

```
Invalid URI: Illegal character [@] found at position xxx
```

Because the first `@` is actually part of the username `userid@salesdeparment`, only second `@` denote the server ip.

Comment: Replace `@` with `%40`

Comment: you can still use -u and -h, like `msyqlsh -u userid@salesdepartment -h 123.45.678.123` but is you want to use the uri format, Barmar's solution is what you are looking for

Comment: The characters that are special in URLs (`/`, `:`, `@`, `?`, `&`, `=` and probably a couple more) must be URL-encoded to represent themselves.